# Code is converting dates into american format?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date, xlsx

I have some code which opens my template and dataset and copies the dataset  into my template workbook. Simple. Well apparently not.

After my code copies this dataset over i have noticed all my dates are being converted into american format. The dataset in question is saved as CSV as this is how it is scheduled out the database.

My plan is to change the data to XLSX format as this seems to fix the problem. But it doesn't explain why its occurring in the first place, any ideas?

```
Dim TemplateWB As Workbook
Dim DataWB As Workbook

'Set Dim and Open files
Set TemplateWB = Workbooks.Open(TemplateFull)   'TemplateFull links to my template file
Set DataWB = Workbooks.Open(DataFull)           'DataFull links to my dataset 

'Make sure sheet is visible within template
TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1").Activate

'Remove any data contained within template
InitialLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
InitialLastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Cells(2, 1).Resize(InitialLastRow, InitialLastColumn).ClearContents

'Select new dataset
DataWB.Sheets("Data_1").Activate

NewLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
NewLastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  Cells(1, 1).Resize(NewLastRow, NewLastColumn).Copy Destination:=TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1").Range("A1")

'Save template and close
        Workbooks(DataFileName).SaveAs (ArchiveFull & Year(Now()) & "_" & Month(Now()) & "_" & Day(Now()) & ".csv")
        Workbooks(ArchiveFileName & Year(Now()) & "_" & Month(Now()) & "_" & Day(Now()) & ".csv").Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a CSV in code, Excel tries to determine the type of data in each column using US settings where possible. You should be able to fix it by specifying the `Local:=True` argument of the `Workbooks.Open` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CDate` when importing dates, it will convert dates to your local settings.

Comment: That's not going to work if Excel already converted them when it opened the file.